# How to log from platform specific module (Android) in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am starting development of my first Flutter app and I would like to know if there is a way how to use breakpoints and logging in classes that are not written in Dart (either iOS or Android specific classes).

I didnt find any mention of platform specific logging in official docs

Answer (score 2):

There are many plugin which can help you to put logs in flutter or if you want to make some custom logerUtils than you can also create your plugin and use in for you project it it very simple and you can find lots of refrence on the internet

also you can use this which provided by flutter as well

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html